# syntax error near unexpected token `fi'

Tags: shell-script

I'm getting a syntax error `unexpected token fi` and `Permission denied` in the following script:

```
cd /home/NorthStar/Dhruva/server-specific-scripts/crons/ResetETA

su postgres -c "psql -d "Dhruva" -f /home/NorthStar/Dhruva/server-specific-scripts/crons/db-connection/query.sql" >> reset.log 2> reset.log

if su postgres -c "psql -d "Dhruva" -f /home/NorthStar/Dhruva/server-specific-scripts/crons/db-connection/query.sql; then 
    printf su postgres -c "psql -d "Dhruva" -f /home/NorthStar/Dhruva/server-specific-scripts/crons/db-connection/query.sql\n' >> resset.log
else
    printf su postgres -c "psql -d "Dhruva" -f /home/NorthStar/Dhruva/server-specific-scripts/crons/db-connection/query.sql\n' >> reset_error.log
fi
```

Comment: why must the lines be *so long*? also, consider `if :; then :; fi >>log`

Comment: or use the character \ for breaking lines so it would be easier to read.

Comment: The hint is in the red `then` and `else` there.

Comment: You realize you've placed your admin password on the Internet for everyone to see, right? I could edit it out, but the damage has been done. Might want to change it to something else...

Answer (score 6):

## Unbalanced quotes

What you have is a messy example of unbalanced quotation marks.

Every pair of single and double quotes must be balanced, meaning, whenever you have an opening quote, you have to have a closing quote later on in the same statement, *and* they must be properly nested. (So, for example, `echo "foo 'bar' baz"` is valid, but `echo "foo 'bar baz"'` is not.

So, in your case, `sh` (or whatever Bourne shell you appear to be using), interprets the quotes *as if* they're balanced, which results in parts of your script being "quoted" which you didn't intend, namely, much of the `if .. else .. fi` construct.

Another (abbreviated) example from your script: `su "psql -d "Dhruva" blah.sql"`. In that example, the string `Dhruva` is actually *outside* the quotes, which is probably not what you intended.

Essentially, your problem is the unbalanced quotes. I will analyze your script a bit more to see if I can't figure out what you're trying to do, and suggest a fixed version, but I confess I don't quite understand your intentions with the script.

## "Fixed" script

I've put "fixed" in [scare-quotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scare_quotes) because even though I can tell you how to repair the syntax of your script, I still have concerns, which I will enumerate at the end of this answer.

### A bit of refactoring, and fixing the quotes

First, you have some very long lines containing repeated elements that can easily be refactored, which already makes our job of "fixing" much easier:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

cd /home/NorthStar/Dhruva/server-specific-scripts/crons/ResetETA

db="Dhruva"
file="/home/NorthStar/Dhruva/server-specific-scripts/crons/db-connection/query.sql"
cmd="psql -d $db -f $file"

su postgres -c "$cmd" >> reset.log 2> reset.log

if su postgres -c "$cmd"; then 
    printf su postgres -c "$cmd" >> resset.log
else
    printf su postgres -c "$cmd" >> reset_error.log
fi
```

While the above is now valid syntax, I do have a few remaining concerns:

- Is there a need to run `$cmd` so many times? Does the output change (i.e., does the query have side effects?) Or can you save the results and append to your log files separately?
- Is `resset.log` a typo, or do you really have three different logs?
- `printf ...` will not do what you (probably) want, here. `printf`s first argument is the format string (in this case, `"su"`), hence, it will print `su`.

Comment: Alternatively, run the sql query just once (instead of 3 times), capture the output in a variable with `$()`, and `printf` the output to different files depending on exit status.

Comment: What is the reason to use `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh` for this script?

Comment: @cas Agreed! I questioned the multiple running in my first bullet point (but you were probably typing your comment while I submitted my edit). I hesitated on suggesting a specific solution for that because of the loose relationship between log files and output streams in the given script.

Comment: @RobertL None in particular. `/bin/sh` would do just as well in this case. I picked `bash` out of a hat as the question didn't specify. I could have mentioned that in my answer, though.

Comment: I think `#!/bin/sh` would be preferred in this case.  `bash` is 9 times larger than `sh` and some systems don't have `bash`.  So why restrict the script to `bash` when it will run with either?  From the `bash` man page: "BUGS  It's too big and too slow."

Comment: @RobertL OK! I submit! You're preaching to the choir, here. :-) I default to `/bin/sh` in my own scripts, but arbitrarily chose `bash` here as I see so many "bash" tags in these U&L SE questions. I'll change it because I, too, adhere to the axiom of "don't use bash when sh will do".

Comment: I don't want you to submit but I'm glad you agree!  I think many people new to scripting think `bash` because it's their login shell, hence so much "bash" in titles and tags.

Comment: Hi, Thanks All for help, but when cron run this script im getting error in log file,,psql:/home/NorthStar/Dhruva/server-specific-scripts/crons/ResetETA/query.sql:2: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ï»¿"
LINE 1: ï»¿

Comment: @rajverma No problem! That `ERROR: ...` you are getting is a PostgreSQL error. Line 1 of your `query.sql` file has an SQL syntax error. To get help with that, ask another question, on [stackoverflow, use the postgresql tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql). Meanwhile, if my answer here helped you with your shell script problem, please consider clicking the checkmark in order to accept it. (You can always ask more questions later!)